# Error executing SSIS package using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis

I try to execute a very simple `SSIS` Package using `C#`.

This package works fine when starting directly in Visual Studio 2015. 
The name of the SSIS package is "Lesson 1.dtsx".

I try to start this process using `C#` with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace run_ssis_project
{
    public class ExecuteSSIS
    {
        public void exePackage()
        {
            String pkgLocation = @"C:\SSIS Tutorial\Lesson 1.dtsx";
            Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package ssisPackage;
            Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app;
            Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult result;

            app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
            ssisPackage = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation,null);

            result = ssisPackage.Execute();

            if(result == Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failure");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

When executing this code, I get an exception:

> "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException", The package
>   failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No
>   further detailed error information.
>
> The exception occurs in line: ssisPackage =
>   app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation,null);

I added two DLLs as references in this project:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll

Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: maybe code can not access package and should be put on server?

Comment: package and code are both on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt have any problem besides that i got an error about mix mode because it was running version 2.0 against a framework with version 4.0. So if this doesnt work you proberbly has an error in your ssis-package. Otherwise try to make a new ssis-packages which basically does nothing and see if you get success.

This is how my code looks like:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;


namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string pkgLocation;
            Package pkg;
            Application app;
            DTSExecResult pkgResults;
            MyEventListener eventListener = new MyEventListener();

            pkgLocation =
              @"C:\Users\thoje\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Integration Services Project8\Integration Services Project8\Package37.dtsx";
            app = new Application();
            pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, eventListener);
            pkgResults = pkg.Execute(null,null,eventListener,null,null);

            Console.WriteLine(pkgResults.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }


    class MyEventListener : DefaultEvents
    {
        public override bool OnError(DtsObject source, int errorCode, string subComponent,
               string description, string helpFile, int helpContext, string idofInterfaceWithError)
        {
            // Output Error Message
            Console.WriteLine("Error in {0}/{1} : {2}", source, subComponent, description);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what i needed to correct in app.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```